# How to run YABOT (Yet Another Build Order) on Mac?

Tags: starcraft-2, macos

My aim is to play single YABOT game, I have downloaded the latest MapCraft(1.6), run it selected a YABOT map but nothing happened when i press launch....is there anything i am missing?? please help and i can locate any detailed step by step install instruction, thanks

Comment: YABOT needs to be run from the Galaxy Editor directly, it does `some things` which require the GE to pull data from other sources.

Answer (score 3):

YABOT maps are now available from the online Custom Map selection:

[image]

This should allow you to play it on both windows and OSX (or even something like WinE)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also. Hit the settings tab and add the path to the Starcraft II application. After this, it should work as expected.